# Total News in the newsgroup

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

I have two models:

1. GroupNews
2. news

I want listed groups news in view by a partial view and show how many news related this group

in groupnews model:

```
public long GroupId { get; set; }
public string Name { get; set; }
```

in News Model

```
public long newsId { get; set; }
public string Title { get; set; }

public long GroupId { get; set; }
```

in controller:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var db = new ApplicationDbContext()
    var CountNews = from p in db.tbl_GroupNews
                    let cCount = (from c in db.tbl_News
                                  where p.GroupId== c.GroupId
                                  select c
                                 ).Count()
                    select new { GroupId= p.GroupId, coun = cCount }

    ViewBag.CountNews= CountNews.Count()}
```

and my partial View

```
@foreach (var item in Model){

<div class="info-box">

    <div class="info-box-content">
        <span class="info-box-text">@item.Name::count of news in this group </span>
        <span class="info-box-number">
         @ViewBag.CountNews
        </span>


    </div><!-- /.info-box-content -->
</div><!-- /.info-box -->}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using foreign key for your database then you can get the counts simply by:

```
 var db = new ApplicationDbContext()
var CountNews = db.tbl_GroupNews.News.Count();
ViewBag.Counter = CountNews;

and if you are not using lazy loading then can get by
var db = new ApplicationDbContext()
var CountNews = db.tbl_GroupNews.Include(w=>w.News).News.Count();
ViewBag.Counter = CountNews;
```

Also in i have an alternative for this, you can get all data for news group:

```
var db = new ApplicationDbContext();
var model = db.groupnew.include(w=>w.News).tolist();
```

And in the partial view you can use:

```
@foreach (var item in Model){

<div class="info-box">

    <div class="info-box-content">
        <span class="info-box-text">@item.Name::count of news in this group </span>
        <span class="info-box-number">
         @item.News.Count()
        </span>


    </div><!-- /.info-box-content -->
</div><!-- /.info-box -->}
```

Comment: Thanks  ; i have a  foreign key but from news to group news  so i cant write : var CountNews = db.tbl_GroupNews.News.Count();

Comment: I can help you on this. You are using code first or database first in entity framework?

Comment: Ok then u can use collection and access child members.